# how to use python Elasticsearch client upsert api

Tags: python, elasticsearch, upsert

I'm using Elasticsearch python client as http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/
I tried hard but still could not find the update api with upsert. Could anyone give me an example with ES python client upsert api please.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The example code is following.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")
es.update(
    index="test",
    doc_type="test1",
    id="1",
    body={
        "doc": {"username": "Tom"}, 
        "doc_as_upsert": True
    }
)
```

If body is without `doc_as_upsert=true` the code would throw an exception when the id is not existing. Additionally, make sure your data were wrapped in `doc`.

Comment: > Additionally, please make sure your data were wrapped in doc{}.

Thank you

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge is it compulsary to use `doc`?

Comment: How to upsert based on a condition?

Comment: So for passing body wrapped in doc, is there a way you can pass it json? It seems it has to be a dict so have to parse json to dict first, but I already have json and wanted to skip a step. I know I can do it using `requests` library and parsing the whole request as json myself. Too bad its not flexible like `helpers.bulk` which takes either. I suppose I could also use bulk and insert 1.

Answer (score 4):

Method `index(*args, **kwargs)` adds or updates a typed JSON document in a specific index, making it searchable.

As pointed out in [Python Elasticsearch Client -> API Documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.index).

Comment: worked for me. not sure what's the difference between this solution and the accepted one (es.update). both worked well for me.

Comment: index rewrites the entire document. For example if you had `{"key": "value"}` and then you use index on the same doc id with `{"key1": "value1"}` the doc will just have `{"key1": "value1"}` while with update you actually have `{"key": "value", "key1": "value1"} `

Comment: also what I found is that with `doc_as_upsert` via `es.update` you couldn't pass pipeline arg

Comment: This _replaces_ the whole document; if you want to do partial updates this doesn’t work (see the accepted answer).