# Not clear how to upsert ElasticSearch using python elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, upsert

Look here for a similar example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33247409/1575066

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")
es.update(index='test',doc_type='test1',id='1',body={'doc' {'username':'Tom'},'doc_as_upsert':True})
```

But now imagine the goal is to append to an array or to increment a previous value (without having to get the document first).

If you go with official requests, this is in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html):

```
POST /website/pageviews/1/_update
{
   "script" : "ctx._source.views+=1",
   "upsert": {
       "views": 1
   }
}
```

I was wondering how to accomplish appending to an array (just simply adding to a default list). It appeared elasticsearch's own examples are easier than anything I can find specifically for Python.

I read a post before about people just using python requests for doing elasticsearch stuff, and I'm thinking there might be a point to it...

Comment: What do you mean by appending to an array? Pretty sure the documentation covers that at `ctx._source.tags+=new_tag`

Comment: @cricket_007 The elasticsearch docs cover it; not the python elasticsearch api docs, unless I missed it...

Comment: The whole JSON block under the `POST <url>` part in the elasticsearch documentation can just be the `body` of the Python API

Comment: did the solution help?

Comment: Left the upserting solution, using Python Elasticsearch, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226831/how-to-use-python-elasticsearch-client-upsert-api/42665903#42665903).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your `script` inside the `body` parameter.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

es.update(
    index="test",
    doc_type="test1",
    id="1",
    body={"script": "ctx._source.tags+=new_tag",
          "params": {
             "new_tag" : "search"
            }
          }
    )
```

More on [update api](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.update)

Here tags is an array and I am appending *search* to it. Also you need to enable scripting for this or you can put script in a file and put that file inside `config/scripts` folder. Syntax might be different depending on ES version. Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: There is a [`script`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.update) parameter, also. Not sure how `params` are added, though

Comment: it is some `url encoded` thing, I have never used it, but you can use body param, from the docs, `body – The request definition using either script or partial doc` which works for me

Comment: Yeah, using the body works. For the url encoded piece, it's probably something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607708/2308683