# Elasticsearch-py update API with script

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to use the Update API via the elasticsearch-py python client on ES 2.1.1 and I'm having trouble.

```
es.index(index='boston', doc_type='stem_map', id=111, body={'word': 'showing', 'counter': 29})
es.get(index='boston', doc_type='stem_map', id=111)

{'_id': '111',
 '_index': 'boston',
 '_source': {'counter': 29, 'word': 'showing'},
 '_type': 'stem_map',
 '_version': 1,
 'found': True}

upscript = {
    'script': {
        'inline': 'ctx._source.counter += count', 
        'params': {
            'count': 100
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried both of the following:

```
es.update(index='boston', doc_type='stem_map', id=111, body=upscript)
es.update(index='boston', doc_type='stem_map', id=111, script=upscript)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', '[John Walker][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]')
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: This also does not work

```
es.index(index='boston', doc_type='stem_map', id='111', body={'word': 'showing', 'counter': 29})

{'_id': '111',
 '_index': 'boston',
 '_shards': {'failed': 0, 'successful': 1, 'total': 2},
 '_type': 'stem_map',
 '_version': 1,
 'created': True}

upscript = {
   "script" : "ctx._source.counter += count",
   "params" : {
      'count': 100
   }
}

es.update(index='boston', doc_type='stem_map', id='111', body=upscript)

WARNING:elasticsearch:POST /boston/stem_map/111/_update [status:400 request:0.002s]
...
RequestError: TransportError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', '[Atum][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]')
```

ANSWER: My mistake. I didn't realize I had to enable scripting on ES first by changing the config/elasticsearch.yml file. My original code works after enabling scripting.

Comment: You could see this post   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046765/not-clear-how-to-upsert-elasticsearch-using-python-elasticsearch

Comment: Yes was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think your `upscript` is the wrong format. Try this

```
upscript = {
   "script" : "ctx._source.counter += count",
   "params" : {
      'count': 100
   }
}
```

And use `body=upscript`.

Using `script=upscript` doesn't work because that requires a url-encoded string of `ctx._source.counter += count` with the body being `{"params" : { "count" : 100 }}`.

Comment: `upscript = {
   "script" : "ctx._source.counter += count",
   "params" : {
      'count': 100
   }
}

es.update(index='boston', doc_type='stem_map', id=111, body=upscript)
`
This still gives me an error:

`RequestError: TransportError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', '[Atum][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]')`

Comment: Your id parameter should be a string, not an int. Other than that, are you sure the index and doc_type are correct?

Comment: Yep. Still doesn't work. See my update. It clearly shows that the document is indexing correctly with the same index and doc_type.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I did not realize that I had to first enable scripting on elasticsearch. My original code works after enabling scripting.

Comment: Oops. Just saw this. Was your original code correct, or was I also right with the upscript?

Comment: Both your version of the upscript and my version worked with the body parameter, so we were both right!