# Why index keep on creating while hitting the api in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

code is below

```
r = [{'eid': '1', 'data': 'Health'},
 {'eid': '2', 'data': 'countries'},
 {'eid': '3', 'data': 'countries currency'},
 {'eid': '4', 'data': 'countries language'}]
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.cluster.health()
es.indices.create(index='my-index_1', ignore=400)

for e in enumerate(r):
    es.index(index="my-index_1", body=e[1])
search1 = es.search(index="my-index_1", body={'query': {'term' : {'data.keyword': 'Health'}}})
search1
```

First time out is below

```
{'took': 0,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': None,
  'hits': []}}
```

Second time

```
{'took': 0,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 1, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 1.2039728,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'my-index_1',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': 'Rov4UHMBpo0uANDoY2_5',
    '_score': 1.2039728,
    '_source': {'eid': '1', 'data': 'Health'}}]}}
```

Third time

```
{'took': 0,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 2, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 1.2809337,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'my-index_1',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': 'Rov4UHMBpo0uANDoY2_5',
    '_score': 1.2809337,
    '_source': {'eid': '1', 'data': 'Health'}},
   {'_index': 'my-index_1',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': 'aov4UHMBpo0uANDonm_E',
    '_score': 1.2809337,
    '_source': {'eid': '1', 'data': 'Health'}}]}}
```

​Below tag are keep on repating while hitting again and again

```
{'_index': 'my-index_1',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': 'aov4UHMBpo0uANDonm_E',
    '_score': 1.2809337,
    '_source': {'eid': '1', 'data': 'Health'}}
```

Is it because of enumerate?. My input is list of dictionary then which having multiple keys, otherwise how to parse this?

My expected out is it should show only one time for every hit
?

Comment: That's the metadata returned by elasticsearch

Comment: @bigbounty, yes, but it  should return its matching, why it keeps on inserting the document into es

Comment: It's the metadata that tells ES uses to search when you fire a query

Comment: What is your document id? Every time you insert, it will create a new doc unless u specify some upsert condition

Comment: @Gibbs go through the link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226831/how-to-use-python-elasticsearch-client-upsert-api`   teied inseting 'doc_as_upsert':True but could not save. any blog or code snippet will help

Comment: @bigbounty, agreed but it should only appear once right, but why it keeps on repeating on every hit?

Comment: @Nons Every document has the metadata associated with it. Hence, for every doc you index, it will be created